# How can I execute JavaScript code from Python?

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, python-3.5

Lets say that I have this code inside a JavaScript file:

```
var x = 10;
x = 10 - 5;
console.log(x);
function greet() {
  console.log("Hello World!");
}
greet()
```

How would I use Python to execute this code and *"print"* `x` and `Hello World!`?
Here is some pseudo code that further explains what I'm thinking:

```
# 1. open the script
script = open("/path/to/js/files.js", "r")
# 2. get the script content
script_content = script.read()
# 3. close the script file
script.close()
# 4. execute the script content and "print" "x" and "Hello World!"
x = js.exec(script_content)
```

And, the expected result would look like this:

```
>>> 5
>>> "Hello World!"
```

Comment: This may help: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyExecJS

Comment: @FailedUnitTest Thank you for the link. Also can the down-voter explain why & how this is too broad?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The module `Naked` does exactly this. `pip install Naked` (or install from source if you prefer) and import the library shell functions as follows:

```python
from Naked.toolshed.shell import execute_js, muterun_js

response = muterun_js('file.js')
if response.exitcode == 0:
  print(response.stdout)
else:
  sys.stderr.write(response.stderr)
```

For your particular case, with file.js as

```
var x = 10;
x = 10 - 5;
console.log(x);
function greet() {
      console.log("Hello World!");
}
greet()
```

the output is `'5\nHello World!\n'`, which you can parse as desired.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and help, appreciate it.

Comment: @Mango glad I could help :)